# R display vector with character and date

Tags: r, vector

Initialized a dataframe to store records with  date, number and character

```
x = data.frame(id = character(),
       city = character(),
       begin_date = as.Date(character(),"%Y-%m-%d"),
       end_date = as.Date(character(),"%Y-%m-%d"),
       number = as.numeric())
 id=1
 city = "New York"
 begin_date = as.Date("2005-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
 end_date = as.Date("2016-12-31","%Y-%m-%d")
 number = 100
 x[1]=c(id,city,begin_date,end_date,number)
```

Desired output:

```
 id      city      begin_date    end_date      number
 20      New York  2005-01-01    2016-12-31    100
```

current output:
      id      city      begin_date    end_date      number
     "1"        "New York" "12784"    "17166"    "100"

Major problem is  the date is not in "%Y-%m-%d"format

How to change to desired output?

Comment: `setNames(c(id,city,begin_date,end_date,number), c('id','city','begin_date','end_date','number'))`? But why not a data frame?

Comment: I used data frame to initialize , but  when I put each record like  above , the date is just in machine time second not in "%Y-%m-%d" format

Comment: This should work: `data.frame(id,city,begin_date,end_date,number)`

Answer (score 0):

Can't mix types in a vector.You can mix types in a list. This replacement works because data.frames are lists underneath.

x[1,]=list(id,city,begin_date,end_date,number)